# How to find 2 values record in table?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula

I'm creating Google Sheet for work, and have problem with advanced formula.

I have one table:

```
Country 1:  Postal code 1:  Country 2:  Postal code 2:
AT          2341            BE          BE4523
DE          D34215          DE          D34215
BE          BE4523          AT          2341
```

I have to merge Country 1 and Country 2 with only 2 digits (f.e. DE34 not DED34) and find this linked in such value table:

```
        AT23    DE34    BE45
   AT23 -       0,15    0,13
   DE34 0,15    -       0,20
   BE45 0,13    0,20    -
```

For example, in the first record, I have to find AT23 + BE45, and fill a cell with value 0,13.

Is it any solution for that?

Comment: This is possible with Google-Apps-Script if you do not mind writing a script, however it is not clear what exactly you try to do - how do you obtain the value 0,13?

Comment: I also don't really get the logic of the tables. Please clarify